# Why are the markers on this map not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I solved!!! In the end it was a silly mistake. I corrected the code and now it's working just fine, i can see the marker where i center the map. All i had to do was to define map before mapMarker.

```
        <%latitudine_4 = session("latitudine") %>
        <%longitudine_4 = session("longitudine") %>
        

        var lat= ('<%=latitudine_4%>')
        var lon= ('<%=longitudine_4%>')

function myMap() {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
var mapProp= {
  center:myLatlng,
  zoom:18,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
  });

}
```

Comment: 1. Please dont ask your queston in the title
2. Please use Code tags
3. Please formate your Code (a little bit)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access `map` before defining it.

Also, have a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#maps_marker_simple-javascript)